# How to connect Pins input/output for the IDE

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have project that need to connect USB device to PC using arduino, The device have power from external power supply and 2 cables of data , so I have do like this :

Pin1,Pin2 = device usb data cabels.

Pin3,Pin4 = Pc usb data cabels.

My question is, how to connect Pin1 to Pin3, and Pin2 to Pin4. is there special Pins I need to connect those cables?

Thank you so much

Comment: What is your "device"? Is it really an USB peripheral? If so, you will need a USB host shield or an arduino mega adk. Even if... Why do you need to put an arduino between the two?

Comment: Hi @frarugi87 , the device is phone, this is exactlly what i need to do, to connect the cabels and dissconct them using arduino and not directly, can i do this using code ?

Comment: If you just have to "disconnect" the phone, maybe you just need to disconnect the 5V cable. Use a P-MOS to let arduino choose whether to power it or not. If the phone can still communicate, look for a USB-capable switch (it needs to support 480Mbit/s communication) and use it to disconnect. Don't even try to interprete the USB communication, otherwise you will just lose your time ;)